# Is there a way view all background jobs/threads in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have a nodejs + mysql application running on AWS on windows (EC2, RDP). I am not if there are treads/loops/jobs running in the background due to my poor coding. Is there anyway to monitor these background stuff which are initiated by my code?

Comment: Depending upon your operating system, you can also monitor from outside the process how many threads are running within a given process.  Remember that node.js uses only one thread for the main execution of your Javascript, but I/O such as disk access may use a small thread pool and your mysql library may also use some threads.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to monitor these background stuff which are initiated by my code?

Yes, the process is called debugging, and in this case, a great JS debugger is "Blink DevTools Debugger"

Among other features you can:

- Navigate in your source files
- Set breakpoints (and specify trigger conditions)
- Step over, step in, step out, resume (continue)
- Inspect scopes, variables, object properties
- Hover your mouse over an expression in your source to display its
  value in a tooltip
- Edit variables and object properties
- Continue to location
- Break on exceptions
- Disable/enable all breakpoints
- CPU and HEAP profiling
- Network client requests inspection
- Console output inspection

A great package implementing this is: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector